# swagger ui rails send headers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, swagger, swagger-ui

I have installed swagger-ui_rails in my project and swagger is working fine but I need to intercept the ajax calls to send a header with the ajax calls on try it out because my api and swagger documentation are on 2 seperate domains. I tried to work with

```
 $.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings) {
        jqXHR.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + $("input[name='auth_header']").val());
    }
});
```

but it is not working, I don't think its possible to change the calls that are being made by the gem, right ? so how can I solve this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself, apparently we can set paramtype header for a field on the api delcaration and then the field gets populated on the swagger ui and gets sent as header in the call.